# DDEX provider is not installed for Oracle.DataAccess.Client error

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have WebForms application, that interact with Oracle database using EntityFramework.
I can open and view .edmx (data model) file without any error, but when I try to perform action `Update model from Database...` after changes to the DB I get the following error:

[image]

I'm using: Oracle 11g 32bit edition, EntityFramework 5.0.0, ODP.NET for Visual Studio 2017.

ODP.NET is installed correctly and I'm able to connect to the DB and view changes (ex. new procedure).

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application I'm currently working on used unmanaged Oracle.DataAccess dll, that is deprecated. Actually, the error was really simple. I have installed ODP.NET provider for Visual Studio but I have forgotten to mobidy .edmx file Schema property. Simple change 
`Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"` with `Provider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"` (right click on the .edmx file and Open is using XML editor).

Comment: I don't think the unmanaged Oracle.DataAccess dll is deprecated. Do you have any source for that statement?